# sql query is slow how to optimise

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFUaO.png)
 this is my exection plan of my query

i want to optimize the query  my table structure is given below

[this is my collection table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zuio.png)

[this is my transaction table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnjnp.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        c.transaction_id, 
        c.property_id, 
        c.ward_id,
        w.ward_no, 
        c.holding_no, 
        c.collector_id, 
        t.payment_mode, 
        t.date, 
        t.payment_ref, 
        t.dd_date, 
        t.bank_name, 
        t.branch, 
        t.amount, 
        t.discount, 
        t.transaction_no, 
        t.pos_no, 
        t.sms_status, 
        t.remarks, 
        ch.id AS cheque_id, 
        ch.check_no, 
        ch.bank, 
        ch.check_date, 
        ch.amount AS chk_amount, 
        ch.reconcilation_date, 
        ch.chk_status, 
        ch.status AS isValid, 
        ch.bank_reconcilation_date, 
        t.penalty
    FROM  
        dbo.tbl_collection_master AS c 
            INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_transaction_master AS t 
                ON c.transaction_id = t.id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_cheque_details AS ch 
                    ON t.id = ch.transaction_id 
            left join tbl_Ward_Master w 
                on c.ward_id = w.id
```

Comment: Any explain/execution plan to show? Which dbms are you using? Table and index definitions?

Comment: why you tagged to `.net` and `c#`? I'm not an SQL developer but still having a doubt, without knowing the table structures and relations how someone can help you to tune up the query?

Comment: Also show the table structures (particularly indexes and primary keys).  Provide information on the current execution plan and the sizes of the tables.

Comment: i am using sql server and sort distinct sort cost 80% shows inexection plan

Comment: Edit your question to add the DDL for tables and indexes. Also, add a link to the actual execution plan uploaded to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. Images of the plan are pretty but mask important details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this problem.

Firstly you could remove the distinct clause from the query. This instantly gives a performance boost and then you can sort for uniqueness in application code/excel/whatever output you are using to move this data on.

Secondly (if not already) you could create clustered indexes on the id columns which you are using to join on. You could also include non-clustered indexes on the other columns being included in the query (do not create non-clustered indexes that include EVERY column in the table as this renders the index useless).

Thirdly you could include fewer columns in your select and then based on the returned values you could execute further queries to get the remaining information. This approach will make your initial load quicker however overall it will take longer to get all of the data.